# CSS mask not working when used files from local computer

Tags: html, css, mask

I have some problem with CSS `mask-image` property. Here is link for working code:
https://codepen.io/Nacho20/pen/MWQrPRy . Ok, but when I try to use images for masking from local computer it stops working. Here is code that does not work:

```
   <html lang="en">
    <head>
 <title>Hello!</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Benton Sans", "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 2em;
           }
      img {
        max-width: 100%;
        display: block;
          }
      .container {
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 1em auto;
                 }
      .container img {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        mask-size: cover;
        -webkit-mask-size: cover;
                 }
      .one {
        -webkit-mask-image: url('image-mask.png');  
        mask-image: url('image-mask.png');  
           }
    </style>
  </head>  
 <body>
   <div class="container">
     <img src="masking-example1.jpg" alt="Balloons">
   </div>
   <div class="container">
    <img class="one" src="masking-example1.jpg" alt="Balloons">
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have downloaded exactly the same images used in the codepen example and have saved them in the same folder as the `html` file that uses them. Some of the properties are probably  unnecessary - `object-fit: cover;` , `mask-size: cover;` and `-webkit-mask-size` , but I have added them here because they were in the original article that i followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-masking-with-mask-image , section **Masking Using Images** .
Also, I have tried a lot of other examples from codepen that are using CSS masks and if I download the used files on my local computer and try to use them as local mask-image files, it stops working.   I also created a couple of times images in Paint 3D with transparent canvas and some non transparent rectangles, triangles ,etc on the canvas and tried to used them as mask-image file, it doesn't work. I checked 3 or 4 similar questions here but I didn't find answer. In some of them there are advices to change settings of server - ok, but I don't use server at all, just local computer.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browsers developer console? If so, please append them to your post.

Comment: I just checked, it is written in console: Access to image at 'file:///C:/Users/home/Desktop/A/image-mask.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
image-mask.png:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Are you running any kind of Webserver like Xampp or Wamp?

Comment: I think I found some kind of solution. Thanks to @Laisender for asking me to see what is written in the  console.  Create a Chrome browser's shortcut. Right-click on the icon and  in properties, edit target to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:/ChromeDevSession" and save. Then using Chrome open the page using ctrl+o. NOTE: Do NOT use this shortcut for regular browsing . It was an answer in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

Comment: @Laisende - I don't. I saw the message in the console and googled it and it pointed the above mentioned link.

Comment: Well as long as it works for you thats fine then